# change UILocalnotification code o UNUserNotification

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to change the below code to UNUserNotification format.I can"t change it into the correct format. Can any one help me?

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
bool neverRepeats = true;
for(id key in _repeatDays) {
    if([[_repeatDays objectForKey:key] boolValue]) {
        neverRepeats = false;
        localNotification.fireDate = _alarmTime;
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Title";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"I'm up, I'm up!";
        localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];



    }
}
if(neverRepeats) {
    if([_alarmTime earlierDate:today] == today) {
        localNotification.fireDate = _alarmTime;
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Title";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"I'm up, I'm up!";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, what errors are you getting?

Comment: UILocalNotification doesn't work in ios10. So I need to change the code into UNUserNotification format. I don't know the basic structure about UNUserNotification

Comment: Did you read the documentation?